# How to parse SVG element's viewBox x, y, width and height values?

Tags: svg, snap.svg

Suppose I have an SVG element :

```
<svg id="myMap" viewBox="0 0 200 200"></svg>
```

How would I get get a specific value
of myMap's viewBox? For a simplified example : how to get the "x" value of the viewBox attribute of myMap? (for the above example, the x value is the first zero (0)).

Below is some variation of syntax I've tried :

```
<script>
  var myMap = Snap("#myMap");
  alert(myMap.attr("viewBox"));//dislays [object Object]
  alert(myMap.attr("viewBox.vbx"));//also dislays [object Object]
  alert(myMap.attr("viewBox.x"));//also dislays [object Object]
</script>
```

All the above examples display [object Object] on the alert box.
I need the proper float value of x, y, width and height of the viewport to implement zoom in and out functions in a map.

Comment: Did one of the answers help? Then you should decide to mark it as accepted. Or tell us, what is missing.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I chose @Robert's answer because I need the values to be used in math calculations. For Joachim's, because      var testXvar=console.log(attr.x);    alert(testXvar); displays nothing, I cannot use that solution.

Comment: What I really after is the member variable name of the viewBox object of an SVG element. If we know their name, we can simply interrogate the viewBox object with  for example   var vbx = myMap.attr({"viewBox"}).x; . but since it seems nobody know the variable name of this viewBox object, i think @Robert's answer is sufficient enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could always just read it straight out of the DOM

```js
alert(document.getElementById("myMap").viewBox.baseVal.width);
```

```html
<svg id="myMap" viewBox="0 0 200 200"></svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `attr()` method returns an object instead of a scalar, while `alert()` needs a scalar. If you use `console.log()` instead of `alert()` you can see the contents of the objects in your JavaScript console.

To get x, y, width and height of your `svg` use

```
var myMap = Snap("#myMap");
var attrs = myMap.attr("viewBox");

console.log(attr.x);
console.log(attr.y);
console.log(attr.width);
console.log(attr.height);
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, @Robert Longson

```js
alert(document.getElementById("myMap").viewBox.baseVal.width);
```

```html
<svg id="myMap" viewBox="0 0 200 200"></svg>
```

```js
alert(document.getElementById("myMap").viewBox.baseVal.width);
```

```html
<svg id="myMap" viewBox="0 0 200 200"></svg>
```